# Assign Case to queue without using assignment rules or apex

Tags: case, flow, assignment-rules, queue

We are using Flow to create cases, we need to assign these cases to different queues. Since FLows do no trigger Assignment rules, what other functionality can I use to make this happen without having to use code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done in two ways:
1) Using workflows: Make the workflow fire on only when the record is created.
set the ownerid of case in the  field update

2) in the flow itself you can set the ownerid based on your criteria